# in react, how to change CSS files linked in the head of index.html?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have website template with two styles (rtl - ltr) each with different files for direction. so, how I load each of the styles when I change language (en - ar).

p.s: i use create-react-app.

edit:-

the folder structure

- src

  - css

    - style-rtl.css
    - style-ltr.css
  - images

    - imgFile.jpg
  - index.js

and the style file

```
.div-style {
  background-image: url('../images/imgFile.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so what I did is getting the link tag that has the direction style and changes it's href to the other CSS file, and it works fine.

index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="style-direction" href="/css/style-ltr.css">
```

then in the component, i do something like that

```
const style = document.getElementById('style-direction');
if (lang === 'ar') {
  style.href = '/css/style-ltr.css';
} else {
  style.href = '/css/style-rtl.css';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using create-react-app, it would have a main file **index.js** in the src folder of your project.

This index.js has a line where you would see that they have included the index.css file as follows (3rd line):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
```

This is the method that is suggested to be used if you want to include css files programatically.

You can then modify the index.js code based on a flag for rtl and ltr. For example, you have a flag variable (Say **let ltr = true**) which has either true or false based on the language you have selected.

Then the code can be:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

//Fetch the flag variable's value based on the language selected.
...
//After that variable (say ltr) is fetched do the following code.

if(ltr === true) {
   import './ltr.css';
} else {
   import './rtl.css';
}
```

PS. Above code is just to give you an idea, you can manage the flag in redux store, localStorage etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that but it throws an error, cus I have image URL like this ../image and it can not resolve it although it's correct path

Comment: I ended up getting the link tag that has the direction style and changes it's href to the other CSS file. I post an answer but I'm willing to mark yours as the correct answer if you have solution to the error in my previous comment

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, can you show me your folder structure and the css file please ? I would try to help.

Comment: Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the code which will change style sheet without having to reload the page**

```
import i18next from "i18next"
import { Suspense, useEffect } from "react"
import { useSelector } from "react-redux"

export default function LanguageProvider({ children }) {
  const currentLang = useSelector(({ lang = "en" }) => lang)

  useEffect(() => {
     i18next.changeLanguage(currentLang)
   }, [currentLang])

  if (currentLang === "ar") {
    const links = document.getElementsByTagName("link")

for (let each of links) {
  if (each.getAttribute("lang") === "english") {
    each.href = ""
    each.rel = ""
    each.integrity = ""
    each.crossOrigin = ""
    each.setAttribute("lang", "")
  }
}

for (let each of links) {
  if (each.getAttribute("lang-sheet") === "english") {
    each.href = ""
    each.rel = ""
    each.setAttribute("lang-sheet", "")
  }
}

const bootstrapRTLLink = document.createElement("link")
const rtl2 = document.createElement("link")
rtl2.rel = "stylesheet"
rtl2.setAttribute("lang-sheet", "arabic")
rtl2.href = "/style-ar.css"
bootstrapRTLLink.rel = "stylesheet"
bootstrapRTLLink.setAttribute("lang", "arabic")
bootstrapRTLLink.href = "https://cdn.rtlcss.com/bootstrap/v4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
bootstrapRTLLink.integrity =
  "sha384-vus3nQHTD+5mpDiZ4rkEPlnkcyTP+49BhJ4wJeJunw06ZAp+wzzeBPUXr42fi8If"
bootstrapRTLLink.crossOrigin = "anonymous"

document.head.appendChild(bootstrapRTLLink)
document.head.appendChild(rtl2)
  } else {
const links = document.getElementsByTagName("link")

for (let each of links) {
  if (each.getAttribute("lang") === "arabic") {
    each.href = ""
    each.rel = ""
    each.integrity = ""
    each.crossOrigin = ""
    each.setAttribute("lang", "")
  }
}

for (let each of links) {
  if (each.getAttribute("lang-sheet") === "arabic") {
    each.href = ""
    each.rel = ""
    each.setAttribute("lang-sheet", "")
  }
}

const ltrLink = document.createElement("link")
ltrLink.rel = "stylesheet"
ltrLink.href = "/style.css"
ltrLink.setAttribute("lang-sheet", "english")
const bootstrapLTRLink = document.createElement("link")
bootstrapLTRLink.rel = "stylesheet"
bootstrapLTRLink.href =
  "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
bootstrapLTRLink.integrity =
  "sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2"
bootstrapLTRLink.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
bootstrapLTRLink.setAttribute("lang", "english")

document.head.appendChild(bootstrapLTRLink)
document.head.appendChild(ltrLink)
  }

  if (currentLang === "ar") {
     return <Suspense fallback={<></>}>{children}</Suspense>
  }

  return <Suspense fallback={<></>}>{children}</Suspense>
}
```